# Set image within template (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I would be grateful of any help, I enjoy programming for my own benefit and had written a program to communicate with my media server and MediaPortal in Android.

I now am trying to convert that program to a Windows 10 App using Visual Studio 2017 and Universal Windows Platform and was surprised just how quickly I was able to do that but have come across an issue I can't overcome.
I have spent several days copying and pasting off the internet and am getting nowhere. My problem is when setting or cancelling a recording from the EPG.
I display the EPG in a ListView and when selecting a listview item it sets or cancels the recording depending on the value of IsScheduled.

My listview item will display an image record.png if IsScheduled="True", this all works well but when I select an item to schedule or cancel a recording it successfully sets/cancels the recording but I can't get it to change the image within the selected listview item because it is in a template.
I originally tried style triggers but failed and someone on the internet said uwp doesn't support style triggers, I have also tried EventTriggerBehavior again with no success.
On another search on the internet, someone mentioned using the Live Visual Tree or use some code to do the same.
Using the code I get 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' but have no idea as to how to change the image.

My Xaml code is:-

```
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="MyList" Height="600" Margin="0, 300, 0, 0"  Background="Black" SelectionChanged="MyList_SelectionChanged" IsItemClickEnabled="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Epg">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Width="560">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Image Name="myImage" Source="{Binding RecordImage}" Width="90" Height="45" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="350,5,0,0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

This is where I set the IsScheduled state after selecting the listview item

```
    private void MyList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Epg selectedProgram = listView.SelectedItem as Epg;

    if (selectedProgram.IsScheduled.ToString() == "False")
    {
        selectedProgram.IsScheduled = "True";
    }
    else if (selectedProgram.IsScheduled.ToString() == "True")
    {
        selectedProgram.IsScheduled = "False";
    }
}
```

To summarise, when selecting the listview item I need to set a record image or a blank image to indicate if the recording is set or not.

There have been other questions similar to this but only one regarding changing an image and unfortunately that one didn't help me.

Comment: Is your Epg class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: That helps Sean, is does change the image, the only problem I have now is if I want to cancel a recording which I have just set nothing happens i.e. selecting the same listview item doesn't change it again

Comment: That's because you're using a selection changed event.  If you're clicking on the same thing the selection isn't changing so no event is firing.  Try implementing the Tapped event.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I was trying to clear the selection. The INotifyPropertyChanged and Tapped event works perfectly.